# QED symbol before theorem name

Tags: symbols, legrandorangebook, qed, theoremname

I'm writing a book using LegrandOrangeBook.cls version 3.1.

Every time I state an example by using theoremstyle, a QED symbol appear before the theorem name. How to write that example without QED symbol in front of it?

MWE is as follow:

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn, a4paper]{LegrandOrangeBook}

\usepackage[bahasa]{babel}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}


\begin{document}  
    \begin{contoh}  
        Jika diketahui himpunan $ A = \{a,b,c\} $ maka power set dari himpunan $ A $ adalah $ \mathscr{P}\{A\} =\{ \varnothing, \{a\},\{b\}, \{c\}, \{a,b\},\{a,c\},\{b,c\},\{a,b,c\} \}$  
    \end{contoh}  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is solved. I change

```
\theoremstyle{blacknumex}
```

into

```
\theoremstyle{blacknumbox}
```

of the theorem declaration

```
\newtheorem{exampleT}{Example}[chapter]
```

in `LegrandOrangeBook.cls`